# How to print RichEditBox content (RTF file) in windows store app

Tags: c#, printing, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have an app which contains a `RichEditBox` and image element and some textblocks. I want to print those data in appropriate format. I have already seen print sample of MSDN, but I am not getting a way to print `RichEditBox` content as it is in RTF format, So how can I paginate that and print that ? I will feel glad if you help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to ur question :

```
        string str = null;
        rtBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.NoHidden, out str);
```

Comment: Not working bro, I am getting just text without formatting :(

Comment: please explain ur requirements ... Like paginate ... and do u want the code to print ?

Comment: It is obvious I have to use `RichTextBlockOverflow` to paginate. Now in that I have to take `Run` and `Paragraph` then what should be the Text property of `Run` ? You just try like take a `RichEditBox` and write code for printing from sample of MSDN. Now paste some formatted text and print, you will understand my problem.

Comment: ok ... ill definitly look into it tomorrow .. as I dont have a sstem presently